# Redeclare template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I am working on C++ template HAL (Hardware Abstraction Library). I trying to create register abstraction which takes register's address as a template parameter as `uint32_t` or as pointer, but I don't know how to do it because it causes template parameter overloading.

Incorrect example which cause redeclare parameter error:

```
template<uint32_t addr>
struct reg
{
   ...
};

template<uint32_t* addr>
struct reg
{
   ...
};
```

I thought about template specialization:

```
template<class T> 
struct reg {};

template<>
struct reg<uint32_t>
{
   ...
};

template<>
struct reg<uint32_t*>
{
   ...
};
```

But I can't get the actual address value this way.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need this value to be a template parameter in the first place?

Comment: Same, why do you need this? Template pointers only work for global variables.

Comment: @Quimby 'HAL' and 'registers' smell a bit like embedded environment... If so, the registers typically *are* global variables. I'm rather wondering why needing both address value *and* pointer. If there are registers of different size, maybe `template <typename T, T* Address>` might be an interesting alternative...

Comment: Yes, it's embedded. MCU's library just define their addresses, e.g. `#define GPIOA_BASE 0xdeadbeaf`. I wan't override this template with pointer to make unified abstraction. E.g. use global variable same way as register e.g. for host debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, an `auto` template parameter solves it neatly:

```
template <auto addr>
struct reg;

template <std::uintptr_t addr>
struct reg<addr> { /* ... */ };

template <auto *addr>
struct reg<addr> { /* ... */ };
```

Comment: I would suggest marking this solution as requiring C++17 and incorporate @Aconcagua 's commentary as an alternative for previous language standards.